# I have a form page that I want to send emails from but

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

```
function Getqueryandsend(){
  alert("!")
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const fname = params.get("fname")
  const lname = params.get("lname")
  const email = params.get("email")
  const messeage = params.get("fname")
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'example@gmail.com',
      pass: 'example'
    }
  });
  
  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'example@gmail.com',
    to: "example@gmail.com",
    subject: 'from' + fname + ' ' +lname,
    text: 'Dear Rashed <br></br>' + messeage
  };
  
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      alert("something went wrong")
    } else {
      alert("messeage sent")
    }
  });
}
```

The code that in there is JSX it is out of the main function with the return I adde'd the email minute ago could that have affect or if anyone has another solution like SMTP please send it to me. for some reason it only runs a part of the code not the entirety it also doesn't give error message.

Comment: You can't run nodemailer in the browser

Comment: You should call an api with the data you have/need and this endpoint, on the server, sends the email, using nodemailer or whatever.

Comment: do you know how can I do it